# Printing the content of all html files in a directory with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I opened a directory, containing 200 html files using BeautifulSoup, but when I try to print the content of the all directory with `print(soup.prettify())` it only shows the content of only one HTML file. The same happens if I try `soup.find('title')`, it only loads the title of the same HTML file as before. Can you tell me why ? Python does not show any error and I cannot understand what is wrong in my code.

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import errno

dir_path = '/directory/path/to/folder/'
files = glob.glob(dir_path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
            print(type(soup))
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise

print(type(soup))
soup.find('title')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [glob](/questions/tagged/glob) module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)). So, pass the `dir_path` argument as a pattern that matches all the HTML file names, by making use of the wildcard character `*`. Try doing:

```
dir_path = '/directory/path/to/folder/*.html'
```

Comment: I tweaked your code a bit and it worked for me. But my files were stored in a drive partition other than where I was working, because it did not seem to work in the same partition. Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're passing a directory path to `glob` instead of a file path specification (see the [documentation for `glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)). Assuming you want to parse every HTML file in the `student` directory, you can define the path as:

```
dir_path = '/directory/path/to/folder/*.html'
```

Note the wildcard `*`, which means that `dir_path` will match any HTML file in the `student` directory.